# Responsive CSS Sprite (top to bottom sprite)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sprite

I am looking for a responsive sprite. I was able to find many posts that has a width (left to right sprite image) but not a top to top bottom sprite that is responsive.

I have a sprite on my responsive site and it looks great in the full sized desktop window, but the sprite itself is not responsive for screen sizes.

This is my CSS:

```css
div.dylansprite {
width:850px;
height:250px;
background:url(../images/Dylan-sprite.png) -0px -0px;
}

div.dylansprite:hover {
background:url(../images/Dylan-sprite.png) -0px -100%;
}
```

and this is my HTML:

```html
<div class="dylansprite"></div>
```

This shows the sprite properly and during hover in the full sized window, but when you shrink the window to make it responsive this image stays full sized. Breaking my responsive site.

I realize I have to put a percentage on the width somewhere I just dont know how to do this. That is show a top (no hover) to bottom (on hover) sprite but use the width to resize according to window width.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
div.dylansprite {
    width:850px;
    height:250px;
    background:url(../images/Dylan-sprite.png) -0px -0px;
    background-size: cover
}
```

The `background-size: cover` keeps the aspect ratio the same

Comment: I added the code you suggested "background-size: cover" but the image is still not responsive. You can see the image here: http://www.dylan.zone/ its the large homepage sprite (Dylan.Zone) on the top.